# How can I implement a more modular CLI by getting command and sub-command containers from ArgumentParser?

Tags: argparse

I have a large git-like CLI with many commands, sub-commands, and arguments. However, most Argparse tutorials only show simple CLIs that use a single file. This approach worked but resulted in a massive module that was difficult to maintain. I partially succeeded in making the code base more modular by creating a class for each command, passing in the command container (created by `parser.add_subparsers`), and adding the command to the command container.

This worked great until I ran into a command that had lots of sub-commands. Although I could take the same approach and pass in the sub-command container (`command.add_subparsers`) to each sub-command, it seems like a better approach would be to invert control and have each command and sub-command get (or create and get) their respective  containers. This should be straightforward because every sub-command knows its parent command. For example, if I have the following structure:

```
command1  
command2  
  subcommand_A
  subcommand_B
command3
```

I would like to add sucommand_B doing something like:
`parser.get_container(command="command2", subcommand="subcommand_B").add_parser(subcommand_B)`.

This seems possible, but not recommended, because the containers are buried deep within private attributes in ArgumentParser.

**Is there a good way to retrieve the command and sub-command containers from the parser (i.e., ArgumentParser)? If not, how else can I make my commands and sub-commands more modular?**

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a lot SO questions about `argparse`, and tried to follow all relevant bug/issues.  Multifile organisation has not been discussed.  Some third party package have tried to extend `argparse`.  Years ago I discovered `argparse` via the `plac` package on the pypi repository.

`ipython/jupyter` also uses (or atleast used to) its own variation of `arpgarse`, building a the arguments from `config` files.  And the `magics` use a argparse like parser.

Have you looked at the `argparse.py` code?  It's well written using classes, including several abstract 'container' ones, as well as the `parser` and `action` class that the user creates.  Many attributes are "public", but some useful ones are also "semi-private" (in python's loose sense).

I'll try to illustrate with a simple case:

```
In [1]: import argparse

In [2]: parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
In [3]: a1 = parser.add_argument('-f','--foo')    
In [4]: sp = parser.add_subparsers(dest='cmd')    
In [5]: sp1 = sp.add_parser('cmd1')    
In [6]: a2 = sp1.add_argument('-b','--bar')
```

Each command returns an object

The parser itself:

```
In [7]: parser
Out[7]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipykernel_launcher.py', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)
```

`._actions` is a useful list that contains all `Action` subclass objects that we created (including the automatic help).

```
In [8]: parser._actions
Out[8]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, required=False, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-f', '--foo'], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, help=None, metavar=None),
 _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices={'cmd1': ArgumentParser(prog='ipykernel_launcher.py cmd1', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)}, required=False, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

Note, that list includes the `subparsers` Action that we assigned to `sp`.  To `parser`, `sp` is just another positional argument. All of its special behevior is enbedded in its subclass definition.

```
In [9]: sp
Out[9]: _SubParsersAction(option_strings=[], dest='cmd', nargs='A...', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices={'cmd1': ArgumentParser(prog='ipykernel_launcher.py cmd1', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)}, required=False, help=None, metavar=None)
```

And the subparser, is another `ArgumentParser` object, with its own `_actions`:

```
In [10]: sp1
Out[10]: ArgumentParser(prog='ipykernel_launcher.py cmd1', usage=None, description=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=True)

In [11]: sp1._actions
Out[11]: 
[_HelpAction(option_strings=['-h', '--help'], dest='help', nargs=0, const=None, default='==SUPPRESS==', type=None, choices=None, required=False, help='show this help message and exit', metavar=None),
 _StoreAction(option_strings=['-b', '--bar'], dest='bar', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, required=False, help=None, metavar=None)]
```

So you can discover everything these objects "know" about each other by looking at the attributes, both ones with and without the '_' header.

For help formatting purposes all Actions are part of an `Action_group`.  But that's another layer of organisation, that is not  used during parsing (expect for mutually_exclusive_groups).

To summarize, there isn't anything within `argparse.py` that aims to facilitate multi-file organization.  But I imagine its class organization could be exploited to make that easier.